# htaccess remove directory from full URL with string

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I want htaccess to remove directory (/thedir/) from full URL but it's not working.  I only want to remove the /thedir/ from this URL not other urls.

```
redirect 302 /thedir/?s_id=ff7d7ds7&bmt_source=facebook&bmt_camp=octy-slant&bmt_medium=ball  https://example.com/?s_id=ff7d7ds7&bmt_source=facebook&bmt_camp=octy-slant&bmt_medium=ball
```

**Also tried**

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^/thedir/?s_id=ff7d7ds7&bmt_source=facebook&bmt_camp=octy-slant&bmt_medium=ball    
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/?s_id=ff7d7ds7&bmt_source=facebook&bmt_camp=octy-slant&bmt_medium=ball [R=302,L]
```

These examples do not remove /thedir/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these rules in your .htaccess file.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule (.*) $1\.php [L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+thedir/([^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (?!^thedir/)^(.*)$ /thedir/$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: Thanks.  I need it only for the URL displayed on the first post NOT all URLs.  Does that make sense?